# Log off users remotely

Tags: powershell, remote-access, logoff

found this script to log off a single username

```
$scriptBlock = {
     $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

      try {
         ## Find all sessions matching the specified username
         $sessions = quser | Where-Object {$_ -match 'username'}
         ## Parse the session IDs from the output
         #foreach($sessionsUser in $sessions){
         $sessionIds = ($sessions -split ' +')[2]
         Write-Host "Found $(@($sessionIds).Count) user login(s) on computer."
         ## Loop through each session ID and pass each to the logoff command
         $sessionIds | ForEach-Object {
             Write-Host "Logging off session id [$($_)]..."
             logoff $_
         }
         #}
     } catch {
         if ($_.Exception.Message -match 'No user exists') {
             Write-Host "The user is not logged in."
         } else {
             throw $_.Exception.Message
         }
     }
 }

 ## Run the scriptblock's code on the remote computer
Invoke-Command -ComputerName NAME -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Is it possible to do the same for all users logged in session ?

I know that -match return first parameter , i tried to do " -ne $Null" but it returns a whole column with sessions instead a row and only check row [0] and the ones with actuall parameters ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through the collection and logoff all the Id present:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    $Sessions = quser /server:$Computer 2>&1 | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
        $CurrentLine = $_.Trim() -Replace '\s+',' ' -Split '\s'
        # If session is disconnected different fields will be selected
        If ($CurrentLine[2] -eq 'Disc') {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                UserName = $CurrentLine[0];
                Id = $CurrentLine[1]
            }
        }
        Else {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                UserName = $CurrentLine[0];
                Id = $CurrentLine[2]
            }
        }
    }
    $Sessions | ForEach-Object {
        logoff $_.Id
    }
}


Invoke-Command -ComputerName gmwin10test -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

Comment: Got an error : At line:4 char:29
+                 $sessions = quser -split '`r`n'
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invalid parameter(s):String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: Yeh, my bad - it's pulling more than when run locally.

Comment: yup that works , still i need to learn much ... have problem with strings options like replainc skiping ect .. .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$sessions = quser | Where-Object {$_ -match 'username'}
## Parse the session IDs from the output
#foreach($sessionsUser in $sessions){
$sessionIds = ($sessions -split ' +')[2]
```

use:

```
$sessionIDs = @()
$sessions = (quser) -split '`r`n'
for ($i=1;$i -lt $sessions.length;$i++){
    $sessionIDs += $sessions[$i].substring(42,4).trim()
}
```

This way all sessions are recorded and the IDs are added to the `$sessionIDs`-array.
I'm using `substring` since the regex is not working if the session is disconnected. Also using `for`instead of `foreach` since the first entry is the header ("ID").

Comment: i got error when i execute this $sessions = quser -split '`r`n' line quser : Invalid parameter(s)
At line:1 char:13
+ $sessions = quser -split '`r`n'
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invalid parameter(s):String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: @WiktorKostrzewski the `quser` probably had to be in paranthesis. Edited my answer.

Comment: @hcm, can we modify the command into (quser) -split '`r`n' | Where-Object { $_ -match 'Person.Name' } so it only logs off the specific username?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer problem is that the result from `quser` is no PS object, so you cannot use CMDlets like `where-object`. You'd have to further extract info from the output with substring or similar, so that you are able to create a connection between username and sessionID.